# Socrata - Is there any way to get list of cities whose crime data is available on Open Data?

Tags: socrata, opendata

I wanted to know how can I get list of cities in US whose crime data is available Socrata dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socrata has the [Open Data Network](http://www.opendatanetwork.com) where you can search across all Socrata portals. It has an underlying API so you can do it programmatically as well.